# validation inside iron-form stops working if readonly attribute of paper-input is set

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have iron-form and paper-input type='text' with value binding, required attribute and error-message attribute.

```
<form is="iron-form" id="form" method="post" action="/form/handler">
   <paper-input type="text" label="[[part.label]]" value="[[part.value]]" name="[[part.key]]" required error-message="Invalid input!"></paper-input>
</form>
```

Validation works just fine and I see my error-message BUT if I set readonly attribute to my paper-input validation stop working.

```
<form is="iron-form" id="form" method="post" action="/form/handler">
   <paper-input type="text" readonly label="[[part.label]]" value="[[part.value]]" name="[[part.key]]" required error-message="Invalid input!"></paper-input>
</form>
```

Logically speaking this is a bug because required attribute is still set but no validation happens.

I still want validation to work even with readonly attribute.. How to do that?

Comment: finally I solve it by adding the following: on-keydown="_manualInput"

_manualInput(e) {
       e.preventDefault()
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT] This is by design: [HTML 5 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-readonly)

> **Constraint validation**: If the readonly attribute is specified on an input element, the element is barred from constraint validation.

---

[ORIGINAL] It seems to be a native issue (or non functionality), this will also fail:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" required readonly name="firstname">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" required name="lastname">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<p>Note that the form itself is not visible.</p>

<p>Also note that the default width of a text input field is 20 characters.</p>

</body>
</html>
```